# Has the USA been stealing oil from Syria?

Tags: politics, syria

It has been widely claimed that the US has been stealing oil from Syria.

For example:

- China's [Global Times](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202208/1274216.shtml), August 2022:

> On August 8, the Syrian Oil Ministry said that the US and its mercenaries were stealing an average of 66,000 barrels of oil per day in Syria, about 80 percent of Syria's daily oil production.

- The [American Conservative](https://www.theamericanconservative.com/donald-trumps-boneheaded-plan-to-steal-syrian-oil/), November 2019:

> [President Trump] decided to deploy U.S. personnel to steal Syria’s oil. He announced that Washington would remain around al-Tanf in southern Syria to guard oil fields captured by the Kurds. Indeed, the number of Pentagon forces are expected to eventually number around 900, almost as many as the number withdrawn from the north. As some Americans leave, others are being deployed—to seize another nation’s resources. Indeed, the president said the U.S. will be “keeping the oil.”

- [Quora: Is the United States stealing Syria's oil?](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-United-States-stealing-Syrias-oil)

Is there evidence of this "theft"? Has the US Government provided an explanation?

Comment: Is it possible to migrate this question to Politics ?

Comment: @Genorme I don’t think that this question would be well received on politics as it can be seen as an attempt to discredit someone which is a close reason.

Comment: I understand **US** but not **SAA**. What is that? Neither 'SAA' nor 'S.A.A.' appears in the linked article about Trump, nor does a search of the article for 'Syria' reveal what it could mean. Is it 'Stealing Ancient Artifacts'?

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess it's the [Syrian Arab Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_Army). Both loyalists and the opposition are often referred to by their armed forces' names (SAA and [SDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_Democratic_Forces), respectively) in media.

Comment: @JoeW  I don't understand the implication you mentioned; you could teach me more. Discrediting someone on Quora is a close reason on SE?

Comment: @dodo Nobody mentioned Quora. Genorme had suggested migrating this question to [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) (which I see you've now done), and Joe W was explaining that, on Politics.SE, questions can be closed if they're deemed to be an attempt to discredit someone or something. This question *may* be closed on Politics.SE for that reason, but it's hard to say.

Comment: @F1Krazy Could you or Joe W be clear that exactly who feel discredited by this question? What is "someone" exactly?

Comment: Made a significant edit: hopefully, it is no longer considered a push-poll. I note a potential confusion between 2019 *plans* and 2022 *actions*, and I invite answerers to be clear on this.

Comment: Is this because Kurds are selling oil to UIS and Al Assad's Syria is not happy?

Comment: This has now been cross posted on politics.se https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/76909/how-did-us-respond-to-the-accusation-of-stealing-syrian-oil

Comment: @borjab That was my guess (which was edited out). However, there is one opinion that the US won't officially recognize the Kurds as it will cause too much frictions with other middle east countries around.

Comment: @dodo just mention Turkey explicitly. Only US ally in the region with a strong negative opinion about the Kurds.